# Connect Wireless and Wired network

Tags: linux, wifi, access-point

What is the best solution to connect a wireless to a wired network, so that both get their IP from one DHCP server and can communicate with each other as if they were the same network? The wireless access point is a Debian box with a prism54 USB-Dongle and a wired interface.
I've already read about bridging, but to my understanding I would need a third network adapter so that the router itself has a way to connect to the network, or is that a misinterpretation on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you'd set up the Debian Box exactly like any other gateway between two network interfaces. Routing tables are the key here. No need for a third interface.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, bridging is the key to do that.

No, you don't need a third network adapter if I got your network right.

See http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the current wired connection is in use, add the second interface (eth1):

```
                    +-------------------------+
                    |                         |
THE INTERNETS <---> | eth0    debian    wlan0 | <---> wireless clients
                    |                         |
                    |          eth1           |
                    +-------------------------+
                                ^
                                |
                                v
                             Local wired
```

You could bridge wlan0 and eth1 together or just leave them on different networks and let your debian box route between them.  Separate networks might be nice if you want to set up some restrictions between the two networks at some point.